# In Unix Shell, how can I navigate, aka move the cursor position more than one character at a time?

Tags: shell, unix, command-line

I'm using SSH Shell to work with a Unix system and I have a really long query in the command that I would like to edit.

However the part I need to edit is way at the beginning and the only way for me to get there is to hold down the left arrow button for about a minute (each time I need to make a new edit).

Is there a faster way to navigate?

Comment: holding CTRL+arrow_key or pressing Home button doesnt work?

Comment: The relevant control sequences depend on your shell.  Is it bash, csh, ksh, zsh, ash, fish, ... ?

Comment: Assuming Bash on PC Linux, usually you can try <key>Pos1</key>, <key>End</key>, <key>Ctrl+A</key>, <key>Ctrl+E</key>, <key>Ctrl+Left</key>, <key>Ctrl+Right</key>

Comment: @Jeribo nope. And pressing `Home` prints `^[[2~` on the screen. No good

Comment: @jwodder How do I find out?

Comment: Wow - jeribo, jwodder, and Jo So - are you guys related?

Comment: `ps -p $$` to find out with shell you are using

Comment: @chaos this is what I get: `PID TTY TIME CMD 2057 pts/15 00:00:00 tcsh`

Comment: @Imray so your are runnning a `tcsh` use `bindkey -e`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a ahell with emacs mode command line editing commands you can use the following **movement commands** ([Here](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html) a complete reference):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> Move to the start of the line.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> Move to the end of the line.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> Move forward a word, where a word is composed of letters and digits.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> Move backward a word.

You may be a bit faster with these.

**To get emacs mode with the different shells:**

`bash`: you have to do nothing

`ksh`: invoke with `ksh -o emacs`

`tcsh`: call `bindkey -e`

**Edit: to find out the shell currently in use:**

```
ps -p $$
```

Example output:

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 3701 pts/1    00:00:00 ksh
```

Comment: `Ctrl-a` works for me but `Ctrl-f` doesn't

Comment: What unicode character would `Ctrl-a` map to for example? Suppose you wanted to pipe that command to another process for example.